# Getting time elapsed in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the time elapsed between two events, for example, the appearance of a UIView and the user's first reaction.

How can I achieve it in Objective-C?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
// do stuff...
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

`timeInterval` is the difference between start and now, in seconds, with sub-millisecond precision.

Comment: @NicolasZozol you can use `fabs(...)` to get the absolute value of a float.  Eg. `NSTimeInterval timeInterval = fabs([start timeIntervalSinceNow]);`

Comment: seems the value of timeInterval is negative.

Comment: if you get a negative value - multiply with -1 and you're good

Comment: Relying on `[NSDate date]` could lead to difficult to track bugs, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17986909/35690) for more info.

Comment: @PinkFloydRocks — What? How would a negative value ever legitimately occur?

Comment: @PinkFloydRocks — Ah! Yes, silly me. I wasn't reading closely enough. It's always either negative or zero. I was mistakenly thinking you were implying it was sometimes negative and sometimes positive. Sorry about that.

Comment: `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]` is a positive value too.

Comment: This approach has unreasonably high CPU/memory overhead AND is subject to time jumps caused by time synchronization, time zone changes, preferences change, etc. Use `CACurrentMediaTime()` or `mach_absolute_time()` instead.

Answer (score 239):

You should not rely on `[NSDate date]` for timing purposes since it can over- or under-report the elapsed time. There are even cases where your computer will seemingly time-travel since the elapsed time will be negative! (E.g. if the clock moved backwards during timing.)

According to Aria Haghighi in the "Advanced iOS Gesture Recognition" lecture of the [Winter 2013 Stanford iOS course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016) (34:00), you should use [`CACurrentMediaTime()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime?language=objc) if you need an accurate time interval.

Objective-C:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

```
CFTimeInterval startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
// perform some action
CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
```

Swift:

```
let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
// perform some action
let elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime
```

The reason is that `[NSDate date]` syncs on the server, so it could lead to "time-sync hiccups" which can lead to very difficult-to-track bugs. `CACurrentMediaTime()`, on the other hand, is a device time that doesn't change with these network syncs.

You will need to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337932/35690) the [QuartzCore framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore?language=objc) to your target's settings.

Note: There are other API's like `clock_gettime_nsec_np` that may work as well.

Comment: Please upvote this. Although I think everyone can agree that NSDate should be your first option, this suggestion resolved an issue of mine. When calling `[NSDate date]` within a completion block within a dispatch block, I was getting the same "current" time that was being reported by `[NSDate date]` immediately before execution hit the point at which my blocks were created. `CACurrentMediaTime()` solved this issue.

Comment: How would we use the elapsedTime for display like mm:ss?

Comment: @CyberMew: That is a separate problem. See [How do I break down an NSTimeInterval into year, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-an) for some solutions.

Comment: Be aware that `CACurrentMediaTime()` stops ticking when the device enters sleep. If you test with the device disconnected from a computer, lock it, then wait ~10 minutes you will find that `CACurrentMediaTime()` does not keep up with wall clock time.

Comment: add and import #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Also, creating `NSDate` objects seems like a useless overhead.

Answer (score 26):

Use the `timeIntervalSinceDate` method

```
NSTimeInterval secondsElapsed = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
```

`NSTimeInterval` is just a `double`, define in `NSDate` like this:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

Answer (score 15):

For anybody coming here looking for a getTickCount() implementation for iOS, here is mine after putting various sources together.

Previously I had a bug in this code (I divided by 1000000 first) which was causing some quantisation of the output on my iPhone 6 (perhaps this was not an issue on iPhone 4/etc or I just never noticed it). Note that by not performing that division first, there is some risk of overflow if the numerator of the timebase is quite large. If anybody is curious, there is a link with much more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378064/588476

In light of that information, maybe it is safer to use Apple's function `CACurrentMediaTime`!

I also benchmarked the `mach_timebase_info` call and it takes approximately 19ns on my iPhone 6, so I removed the (not threadsafe) code which was caching the output of that call.

```
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

uint64_t getTickCount(void)
{
    mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebaseInfo;
    uint64_t machTime = mach_absolute_time();

    // Convert to milliseconds
    mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);
    machTime *= sTimebaseInfo.numer;
    machTime /= sTimebaseInfo.denom;
    machTime /= 1000000; // convert from nanoseconds to milliseconds

    return machTime;
}
```

Do be aware of the potential risk of overflow depending on the output of the timebase call. I suspect (but do not know) that it might be a constant for each model of iPhone. on my iPhone 6 it was `125/3`.

The solution using `CACurrentMediaTime()` is quite trivial:

```
uint64_t getTickCount(void)
{
    double ret = CACurrentMediaTime();
    return ret * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Anyone know why there is a redundant (void) cast on the mach_timebase_info call?

Comment: @SimonTillson that's a good question - either it was required to silence a warning, or I copied it from somewhere else and just didn't notice to delete it. I can't remember.

Comment: This is not thread safe. `mach_timebase_info()` will reset passed-in `mach_timebase_info_data_t` to `{0,0}` before setting it to actual values, which can cause division by zero if code is called from multiple threads. Use `dispatch_once()` instead (or `CACurrentMediaTime` which is just mach time converted to seconds).

Comment: Thanks @wonder.mice, I have updated my answer (found an issue regarding quantisation as well, I blame 6-year-younger me...)

Answer (score 8):

For percise time measurements (like GetTickCount), also take a look at mach_absolute_time and this Apple Q&A: http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html.

Answer (score 4):

use the timeIntervalSince1970 function of the NSDate class like below:

```
double start = [startDate timeIntervalSince1970];
double end = [endDate timeIntervalSince1970];
double difference = end - start;
```

basically, this is what i use to compare the difference in seconds between 2 different dates. also check this link [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSince1970)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct (with a caveat*). I add this answer simply to show an example usage:

```
- (void)getYourAffairsInOrder
{
    NSDate* methodStart = [NSDate date];  // Capture start time.

    // … Do some work …

    NSLog(@"DEBUG Method %s ran. Elapsed: %f seconds.", __func__, -([methodStart timeIntervalSinceNow]));  // Calculate and report elapsed time.
}
```

On the debugger console, you see something like this:

```
DEBUG Method '-[XMAppDelegate getYourAffairsInOrder]' ran. Elapsed: 0.033827 seconds.
```

---

*Caveat: As others mentioned, use `NSDate` to calculate elapsed time only for casual purposes. One such purpose might be common testing, crude profiling, where you just want a rough idea of how long a method is taking.

The risk is that the device's clock's current time setting could change at any moment because of network clock syncing. So `NSDate` time could jump forward or backward at any moment.