# NSNumber of seconds to Hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber

I am having a terrible time trying to do something that should be easy. I have a NSNumber value of 32025.89 seconds. I need to represent that in Hours, Minutes, Seconds. Is there a method that spits that out? I can't seem to find a proper formatter.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-and .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried creating an `NSDate` from that and printing that using an `NSDateFormatter`?

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[theNumber doubleValue]];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]); 
[formatter release];
```

If you need the individual values for hours, minutes, and seconds, use `NSDateComponents` as suggested by nall.

The above won't print the correct amounts if the `NSNumber` represents more than one day. It could be 1 day and 1 hour, and it would only print 01:00:00. In such a case you should calculate hours, minutes and seconds manually.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for. I know I could od the math but I was trying to find a way that essentially did it for me -- NSDateFormatter was I guess, what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Using this code I had a user who got an incorrect value - instead of 03:00 for 180 seconds - they got 33:00.  They were in a timezone which was 4.5 hours ahead and I wondered if the half hour in their timezone could possibly have caused this...

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to just divide it out, try this. It may be close enough for your purposes. **Note:** It doesn't account for sub-second precision. (`setSecond` takes an `NSInteger`).

```
NSDateComponents* c = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[c setSecond:32025.89];

NSCalendar* cal = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]
                   autorelease];

NSDate* d = [cal dateFromComponents:c];

NSDateComponents* result = [cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit |
                                           NSMinuteCalendarUnit |
                                           NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                  fromDate:d];

NSLog(@"%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds",
    [result hour], [result minute], [result second]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way without any libraries except for `modf()` from `math.h`:

```
float fsec = 32025.89f, frac = 0;
int milliseconds = (int)(modf(fsec, &frac) * 1000);
int isec = (int)frac;
int hours = isec / 3600;
int minutes = (isec % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = isec % 60;
```

Comment: I just noticed that you divide 0 by 3600 to get hours. That's a typo, right? You means to say "fsec / 3600" right?

Comment: And what does `frexp` have to do with this ??

Comment: um... it extracts the fraction part and the integer part of a floatingh pointer number. In this case, the milliseconds and seconds.

Comment: @Sonny the `frexp(fsec, &isec)` call is filling in isec with the integer part of the fsec value in the process.

Answer (score 2):

NSNumber *valueForDisplay = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:
              [self valueForDisplay:clockName]];

```
NSNumber *totalDays = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:
         ([valueForDisplay doubleValue] / 86400)];
NSNumber *totalHours = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:
         (([valueForDisplay doubleValue] / 3600) -
          ([totalDays intValue] * 24))];
NSNumber *totalMinutes = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:
         (([valueForDisplay doubleValue] / 60) -
         ([totalDays intValue] * 24 * 60) -
         ([totalHours intValue] * 60))];
NSNumber *totalSeconds = [NSNumber numberWithInt:
         ([valueForDisplay intValue] % 60)];
```