# converting "2016-03-02 23:20:40.000 +0000" with dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS Z"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am sorry to ask this question but i can't find the answer.
I try to parse the following String from a server into a NSDate:
**"2016-03-02 23:20:40.000 +0000"**

```
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        let myDate = "2016-03-02 23:20:40.000 +0000"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS Z"

        print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)) //-> nil
```

I found tons of informations about the dateFormat, but nothing helped me out. I also tried different locals, but it was not successfully. 
:(

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hint: look at the docs for date format specifiers and see what `hh` is to be used for and then see what format the hour is in your date string.

Comment: Use `HH:mm:ss` as shown here: [NSNumber of seconds to Hours, minutes, seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528822/nsnumber-of-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds)

Comment: A better duplicate might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657123/swift-nsdateformatter-not-working since it covers the OP using `hh` instead of `HH`.