# Is there some functionality in Cocoa to display time intervals in natural language?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, frameworks, nlp

What I am searching for is a Cocoa (or third party) class that can display time intervals in natural language, e.g.:

- 10 seconds ago
- 1 hour ago
- 2 days ago

Do you know anything that could help me to achieve this task without writing it by myself and melting in if-else hell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one I've originally pointed to does not seem to be there anymore but as pointed out there is [NSDate-TimeAgo](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo), I haven't tried it but looks good to me.

**EDIT:** updated answer to point to existing code

Comment: It looks like timeago is now here:  https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Answer (score 2):

Your question for Cocoa is the same as [this question for Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-and), and the answer to that one will work for you as well, because it uses Foundation, which is in both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

Comment: You don’t really answer my question. All of the proposed solutions in the thread you mention still have to deal with a couple of if-else statements.

But thanks for pointing out the thread anyway.

Comment: The `if (component != 0) /*add component to string*/` statements have to be *somewhere* anyway; how is that a problem? If that's not what you're talking about, then what if statements are you talking about?

Comment: I just searched for third party stuff that does this for me, so I don’t have to.

Answer (score 1):

See `-[NSDateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:]`.

Comment: that only offers very limited options

Comment: Mm, well, recall that you have the rest of the NSDateFormatter API to work with as well.

The main limitation I see is that it always formats with respect to the current date.

Answer (score 1):

I can really recommend Mattt Thompson's [TTTTimeIntervalFormatter](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) - very clean, very functional (lots of other super useful bits and pieces in the same repo).