# Using mod operator in iOS app

Tags: iphone, nstimeinterval, modulus

I have an NSTimeInterval that is stored as a double. I would like to get the amount of minutes that are inide of the second value using the % operator.

```
minutes = secondValue % 60;
```

where minutes is declared as `double minutes`

The result is that XCode says "Invalid operands to binary %"

Thoughts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-and

Comment: Besides getting the modulo to work, doesn't this give the opposite result of what you want? If `secondValue` is 123 (which works out to 2 minutes, 3 seconds), the result of `secondValue % 60` will be 3. It seems like this should be division.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The OP changed their question, so here is my new answer:

You want to do `minutes = floor(secondsValue) / 60;`  You want int division, not modulus.

Comment: you fixed one modulo divide - but, does your suggested code make sense?

Answer (score 13):

From the C standard, section **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**, paragraph 2:

> The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer type.

Comment: This answer makes no sense since the OP edited the question.  Whether or not that's cause for a downvote, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

If secondValue is a float or double, you can use C type casting:

```
minutes = ((int)secondValue) % 60;
```

EDIT:

(If secondValue is too big to fit in an int, this won't work.  So you need to know that the range of your value is appropriate.)