# Mod operator in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, c, modulo

have been searching for a mod operator in ios, just like the `%` in c, but no luck in finding it. Tried the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731167/using-mod-operator-in-ios-app) but it gives the same error. 
I have a float variable 'rotationAngle' whose angle keeps incrementing or decrementing based on the users finger movement. 
Some thing like this:

```
if (startPoint.x < pt.x) {
    if (pt.y<936/2) 
        rotationAngle += pt.x - startPoint.x;
    else
        rotationAngle += startPoint.x - pt.x;   
    }
    rotationAngle = (rotationAngle % 360);
}
```

I just need to make sure that the rotationAngle doesnot cross the +/- 360 limit.
Any help any body. 
Thanks

Comment: Eh, Objective-C extends from C. Therefore C's `%` operator also works in Objective-C. **However** floats cannot do `%` so you need to make it an int first.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `fmod` (for `double`) and `fmodf` (for `float`) of math.h:

```
#import <math.h>

rotationAngle = fmodf(rotationAngle, 360.0f);
```

Comment: Thank u but its working without importing math.h also, very short and precise.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `fmod` function, which does a floation-point modulo, for definition see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/. Examples of how it works (with the return values):

```
fmodf(100, 360); // 100
fmodf(300, 360); // 300
fmodf(500, 360); // 140
fmodf(1600, 360); // 160
fmodf(-100, 360); // -100
fmodf(-300, 360); // -300
fmodf(-500, 360); // -140
```

`fmodf` takes "float" as arguments, `fmod` takes "double" and `fmodl` takes "double long", but they all do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this works, objective c is so diverse, once you call a method like [self methodName:parameters], next line you call a method like methodName(parameters)..

Answer (score 1):

I cast it to an int first

```
rotationAngle = (((int)rotationAngle) % 360);
```

if you want more accuracy use

```
float t = rotationAngle-((int)rotationAngle);
rotationAngle = (((int)rotationAngle) % 360);
rotationAngle+=t;
```

Comment: I don't think its enough to worry about unless you are using it to enter a direction of travel for a spaceship. If it loses any at all witch I don't think it will, there is no rounding, casting, or devision so it won't.