# Difference between two NSDate objects -- Result also a NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdate

I have two NSDate objects and I want the difference between the two and the result should again be a NSDate object. Any idea how to achieve this?

Here, I am trying to address a unique problem where I have to find out the elapsed time and then localize the elapsed time. I can localize it if I have the elapsed time in NSDate object. So thought of creating a NSDate object which has its time component same as time interval between the two dates so that I could use NSDateFormatter to localize it.

Comment: The difference between any two arbitrarily selected dates is always 19th February 1986. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. :-P

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`NSDate` represents an instance in time, so it doesn't make sense to represent an *interval* of time as an `NSDate`. What you want is `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDate *dateA;
NSDate *dateB;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay
                                           fromDate:dateA
                                             toDate:dateB
                                            options:0];

NSLog(@"Difference in date components: %i/%i/%i", components.day, components.month, components.year);
```

Comment: As of iOS 8, the calendar components are now (for this example): `NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay`

Comment: Thanks @AaronAsh, I've updated the answer to reflect the latest constant names.

Comment: In iOS 8 NSGregorianCalendar is deprecated. Replace with NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian

Answer (score 18):

If you subtract 12/12/2001 from 05/05/2002 what will be the date? The chronological distance between two dates can't be a date, it's alway some kind of interval. You can use [timeIntervalSinceDate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to calculate the interval.

To localize you can try the following steps:

- You can use the [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) with dateFromComponents: passing in a [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
- To break down a timeInterval into [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) look at [How do I break down an NSTimeInterval into year, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237778/how-do-i-break-down-an-nstimeinterval-into-year-months-days-hours-minutes-and).
- Finally use the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-BCIGICCF) to get your localized string. The [Date Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007972-SW9) shows the different placeholders.

Comment: I understand this. But I am trying to address a unique problem where I have to find out the elapsed time and then localize the elapsed time. I can localize it if I have the elapsed time in NSDate object. So thought of creating a NSDate object which has its time component same as time interval between the two dates so that I could use NSDateFormatter to localize it.

Comment: @Abhinav I understand, there is a second problem arising: What is a month? Some months have 31 days others have 30. To represent an interval with the term month is very precise. You have to take that into account.

Answer (score 7):

From `NSDate` class reference, you have instance methods to do these -

1. How to compare two NSDate variables? **Ans:** `isEqualToDate:`
2. How to find difference between two NSDate variables? **Ans:** `timeIntervalSinceDate:`

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the time interval between two dates using `NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSinceDate:`, but it doesn't make any sense for you to represent a time interval as a date.

Answer (score 3):

There is a easy way by using -compare: in NSDate:

```
NSDate *dateA = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100];
NSDate *dateB = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:200];
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:150];
NSArray *dateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateA, dateB, myDate, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
if ([myDate isEqualToDate:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:1]])
    NSLog(@"myDatea between dateA and dateB");
```