# Time difference between two times in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, date

I have two times :

10:23:51
10:31:54

Both values are stored as strings in a SQLite database.

I want to find the difference between these two times in hh:mm format.
How can I do this?

I have searched a lot. But can't find a proper solution.
Help me out.
Thanks.

**Edit :**
See basically I am having two arrays:
`InTimeArray` and `OuttimeArray`.
Now in the `viewDidload` method , I am fetching all the `intime` entries in the `IntimeArray` and `Outtime` entries in the `outtime` Arrays.

Now I am passing one by one values in tableview like in 1st row

```
 IntimeArray[0]
 OuyTimeArray[0]
```

second row:

```
 IntimeArray[1]
 OuyTimeArray[1]
```

Now I want to count the differences between 1st row's `intime` and `outtime` in HH:MM format.
I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at that :

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];  
if(!date1) date1= [NSDate date];
[dateFormat release];
[locale release];

return date1;
}
```

this will turn the NSDate to you and when you change them both to NSDates then you can learn the difference by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562594/difference-between-two-nsdate-objects-result-also-a-nsdate).

i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

You have to first change your both strings into date format using this method :-

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string;
```

after that you just have to calculate number of seconds between both the dates.Thats it.

**OR** there is another simple way to do this. i.e.

get dates from both arrays first like this:-

```
NSDate *eventStartDate = [IntimeArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

NSDate *eventEndDate = [OuyTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

Then calculate difference between both the dates like this :-

```
NSTimeInterval startTimeInterval = [eventStartDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
```

Hope it helps Thanks :)

Comment: I have NSDate *eventStartDate = [IntimeArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

NSDate *eventEndDate = [OuyTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

Comment: I have used this code as you said..But it is giving me error regarding Incompatible type "NSInterval"

Comment: I want to take diff between eventStartDate and eventEndDate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:IntimeArray[0]];
NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:OuyTimeArray[0]];

NSTimeInterval ti = [d2 timeIntervalSinceDate:d1];
float hours = floor(ti / 3600);
float minutes = floor((ti - hours*3600) / 60);

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%02.0f",hours,minutes];
```

For your given example, `NSLog(@"Time passed: %@",s);` will print `00:08`.

Comment: hey I am putting my edited code referenced by you..it is giving me error.

Comment: If you get an error, then your `NSString` (which comes out of `IntimeArray[0]`) is not formatted correctly (i.e. "HH:mm:ss"). Make sure that the string has this format by printing it out via `NSLog()` before creating the date.

Comment: In my app it is must to have H:mm:ss format sir...If I will change this format than it will cause so many changes..Is there any way?

Comment: Please post the error that you're getting when running this code.