# how to convert NSDate into formate like days with hours?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate

i have one date like '2014-11-16T15:42:14' in server and now i want to convert this date into such formate like '1 day and 2 hours ago'.
can any body help me how can i solve this?

I wholeheartedly accept your down votes.(Please explain me the reason for you down vote such that i will not repeat my mistake).

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562814/3332367).

Comment: Use NSDateComponents (and -- shudder -- write some code).  A little Googling would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Look at that example that will help you definately.**

[Copied From Here](http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/)

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setWeekOfYear:1];
[components setHour:12];

NSLog(@"1 week and twelve hours from now: %@", [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0]);
```