# How to calculate different between two NSDate variable?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am building an IOS application where I am doing following step.

1. Parsing the data.
2. Getting OpenTime and CloseTime.
3. Set the OpenTime and CloseTime in a NSString variable name as openTime and closeTime.

Now the problem is I want to calculate the different of this two time.

I am getting the value like, 
`OpenTime = "00:15:00"` and `CloseTime = "1:30:00"`

The Time formate is - 24 hours.

Can someone help me in solving this problem I am new in IOS.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Presumably your strings are being delivered from somewhere remote? If you're generating them on the device, just don't store them as strings.

Comment: @Logan. Suppose NSString *openTime = @"00:15:00"; NSString *closeTime = @"1:30:00"; in this 2 string I have Time value and I need a different of this 2 value.

Comment: @Tommy in which dataType I should store and how to calculate the Time different

Comment: @MarcusAdams Suppose OpenTime is - "00:15:00" and closeTime is "00:45:00" then in this case the expected output should be "00:30:00".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between two NSDate objects -- Result also a NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562594/difference-between-two-nsdate-objects-result-also-a-nsdate)

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have two NSDate variables `openTime` and `closeTime`

```
int calendarUnit = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:calendarUnit fromDate: openTime   toDate: closeTime  options:0];

int months = [components month];
int days = [components day];
int hours = [components hour];
int minutes = [components minute];
```

Comment: Doesn't that assume he has `NSDate`s, not `NSString`s?

Comment: see question title "different between two `NSDate` variable"

Comment: I have value in String can you please help in this condition

Comment: @TapasPal and in the text of the question he says "Set the OpenTime and CloseTime in a NSString variable name as openTime and closeTime."

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDateComponents

```
NSDate *date = [self getTimeInDateFormatFromString://your time string]; // your method return nsdate from string using nsformatter
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
```

you can use comp.hour and minute to get time difference.

Comment: Thanks for Answer can you please explain your code in detail

Comment: the converted date will decompose to nsdatecomponents which will return you hour and minute in integer format. You can compare your two dates components to get your required result i.e difference b/w two dates. the following link is with code snippet : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30328363/4916336

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *openTime = @"12:48:00";
NSString *closingTime = @"21:52:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *openDate = [formatter dateFromString:openTime];
NSDate *closeDate = [formatter dateFromString:closingTime];

int calendarUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:calendarUnits fromDate: openDate toDate: closeDate options:0];

NSLog(@"The difference is: %ld hours , %ld minutes, %ld seconds", (long)components.hour, (long)components.minute, (long)components.second);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)compareTwoDate:(NSDate *)start :(NSDate *)end
{
    NSDate *end_date =end;
    NSDate *startDate =start;

    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [startDate    timeIntervalSinceDate:end_date];

    double secondsInMinute = 60;

    NSInteger secondsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInMinute;
}
```

Comment: You might want to tell the OP how to convert the date from string to `NSDate` object and also why you calculate the difference in minutes.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Your start and end time are in NSString OR NSDate format ?

Comment: The OPs dates are in string format.  Also that method should probably `return` something.

Comment: @trojanfoe, have posted the answer below.Here you will Get difference in seconds. Than you can convert in minutes OR Hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *star_array=[@"00:15:00" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSInteger start_time=[[star_array objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]*3600+[[star_array objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]*60+[[star_array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

NSArray *end_array=[@"1:30:00" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger end_time=[[end_array objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]*3600+[[end_array objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]*60+[[end_array objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];

NSInteger diff_seconds=end_time-start_time;
```