# How accurate is NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am trying to get the time difference between two NSDates.

```
NSDate *d1 = somedate;
NSDate *d2 = someOtherdate;
NSTimeInterval sec = [d2 timeIntervalSinceDate:d1];
```

How accurate is NSTimeInterval?
Does it take care of the variation in number of days in a month, for example if the number of days is 28,29,30 or 31? Also time zone difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387360/get-an-accurate-time-difference-between-two-nsdates ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How accurate is NSTimeInterval?

It's accurate to milliseconds (if not more).

> Does it take care of the variation in number of days in a month, for example if the number of days is 28,29,30 or 31?

Yes, the difference will be in seconds. `NSDate` deals with actual days in a month as well as leap years and daylight savings, etc.

> Also time zone difference?

`NSDate` values are always stored in UTC so your `NSDate` objects are always in the same timezone. There is nothing to deal with for this.

Answer (score 3):

`NSTimeInterval` is in fact just a typedeffed `double`. Because `NSDate` represents a single point in time (independent of time zone, calendar, etc.), `NSTimeInterval` represents the number of seconds between the two dates (points in time).

Comment: I don't see any type casting here.

Comment: No, the foundation data type `NSTimeInterval` itself is a typecast `double`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I meant typedef. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: [that's not a typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). That's a typedef.

Comment: Yep, just realized that. Just got my terminology mixed up for a sec. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> How accurate is `NSTimeInterval`

On the platforms I know they have Cocoa, `NSTimeInterval` is typedeffed to `double`,

> Does it take care of the variation in number of days in a month?

It's not `NSTimeInterval` that does that, it's a **type.** It's the various classes (`NSDate`, whatever) that take care of all these deviances. And they do it really well.

Answer (score 2):

`NSTimeInterval` is actually just a typedef for `double`.

`NSDate` encapsulates a time interval and provides an interface to interact with it.

If you want that date to be referenced to our actual calendar, you have to use the `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` classes.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then you can get data out of the components object:

```
components.day
components.week
// etc
```

Assume the Mayan culture never went extinct. This right instant in time would be represented by the same NSDate object, but through a different `NSCalendar` (like a `NSMayanCalendar`) you would get a completely different representation of that date.