# Time between two actions

Tags: objective-c

Trying to record the time it takes for a user to press one button, and then the next.

Here's part of my .m file... I can't get theDate to hold its variable (The start time)  All that happens is I get 0.000 seconds in the log & text label.

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{

    NSDate *theDate = [[NSDate date] init];

}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [theDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeInterval];

    _timeLabel.text = time;
    NSLog(time);
}
```

I also have

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSDate *theDate;
```

in the header file and

```
@synthesize theDate;
```

in the top of the .m file.

Thanks!

BTW I'm trying to go off of this post: [Getting the time elapsed (Objective-c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741830/getting-the-time-elapsed-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate *theDate = [[NSDate date] init];
```

Creates a local variable so it doesn't use your property. In addition, as @Catfish_Man pointed out, `[[NSDate date] init]` should just be `[NSDate date]`.

In addition, you should use `self.theDate` to use the property.

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    self.theDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [self.theDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeInterval];

    _timeLabel.text = time;
    NSLog(time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining date with a local scope in

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender
```

You should be using

```
self.date = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Nope, should be `self.date = [NSDate date];`.

Comment: Fixed, was just trying to answer the original question and copy pasted from his code

Answer (score 1):

You can get **really** fine timing (seconds.parts of seconds) using this StopWatch class.  It uses the high-precision timer in the iPhone.  Using NSDate will only get you second(s) accuracy.

**StopWatch.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface StopWatch : NSObject 
{
    uint64_t _start;
    uint64_t _stop;
    uint64_t _elapsed;
}

-(void) Start;
-(void) Stop;
-(void) StopWithContext:(NSString*) context;
-(double) seconds;
-(NSString*) description;
+(StopWatch*) stopWatch;
-(StopWatch*) init;
@end
```

**StopWatch.m**

```
#import "StopWatch.h"
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

@implementation StopWatch

-(void) Start
{
    _stop = 0;
    _elapsed = 0;
    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}
-(void) Stop
{
    _stop = mach_absolute_time();   
    if(_stop > _start)
    {
        _elapsed = _stop - _start;
    }
    else 
    {
        _elapsed = 0;
    }
    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}

-(void) StopWithContext:(NSString*) context
{
    _stop = mach_absolute_time();   
    if(_stop > _start)
    {
        _elapsed = _stop - _start;
    }
    else 
    {
        _elapsed = 0;
    }
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] Stopped at %f",context,[self seconds]]);

    _start = mach_absolute_time();
}


-(double) seconds
{
    if(_elapsed > 0)
    {
        uint64_t elapsedTimeNano = 0;

        mach_timebase_info_data_t timeBaseInfo;
        mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo);
        elapsedTimeNano = _elapsed * timeBaseInfo.numer / timeBaseInfo.denom;
        double elapsedSeconds = elapsedTimeNano * 1.0E-9;
        return elapsedSeconds;
    }
    return 0.0;
}
-(NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f secs.",[self seconds]];
}
+(StopWatch*) stopWatch
{
    StopWatch* obj = [[[StopWatch alloc] init] autorelease];
    return obj;
}
-(StopWatch*) init
{
    [super   init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The class has a static `stopWatch` method that returns an autoreleased object.

Once you call `start`, use the `seconds` method to get the elapsed time.  Call `start` again to restart it.  Or `stop` to stop it.  You can still read the time (call `seconds`) anytime after calling `stop`.

**Example In A Function**  (Timing call of execution)

```
-(void)SomeFunc
{
   StopWatch* stopWatch = [StopWatch stopWatch];
   [stopWatch Start];

   ... do stuff

   [stopWatch StopWithContext:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Created %d Records",[records count]]];
}
```

There is an equivalent version in C++ (for .mm or .cpp implementations) if you need it.  You can find that [here](https://github.com/NonlinearIdeas/Missile-Demo/tree/master/MissileDemo).

Even if you don't use the class specifically, the general technique will allow you to get high accurate time differences for events.

**NOTE** I could cache the mach_timebase_info_data_t if it is the first time and save the call to get it.  This is older code and does not have that (minor) optimization.