# How can I use mach_absolute_time without overflowing?

Tags: macos, x86, posix, powerpc, darwin

On Darwin, the POSIX standard `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` timer is not available. Instead, the highest resolution monotonic timer is obtained through the `mach_absolute_time` function from `mach/mach_time.h`.

The result returned may be an unadjusted tick count from the processor, in which case the time units could be a strange multiple. For example, on a CPU with a 33MHz tick count, Darwin returns 1000000000/33333335 as the exact units of the returned result (ie, multiply the `mach_absolute_time` by that fraction to obtain a nanosecond value).

We usually wish to convert from exact ticks to "standard" (decimal) units, but unfortunately, naively multiplying the absolute time by the fraction will overflow even in 64-bit arithmetic. This is an error that Apple's sole piece of documentation on `mach_absolute_time` falls into ([Technical Q&A QA1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1398/_index.html)).<sup>1</sup>

How should I write a function that correctly uses `mach_absolute_time`?

---

1. Note that this is not a theoretical problem: the sample code in QA1398 completely fails to work on PowerPC-based Macs. On Intel Macs, `mach_timebase_info` always returns 1/1 as the scaling factor because the CPU's raw tick count is unreliable (dynamic speed-stepping), so the API does the scaling for you. On PowerPC Macs, `mach_timebase_info` returns either 1000000000/33333335 or 1000000000/25000000, so Apple's provided code definitely overflows every few minutes. Oops.

Comment: I have `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` on MacOS 10.13.6, and it fills timespec, returning 0; not sure if it's really monotonic, however.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Most-precise (best) answer

Perform the arithmetic at 128-bit precision to avoid the overflow!

```cpp
// Returns monotonic time in nanos, measured from the first time the function
// is called in the process.
uint64_t monotonicTimeNanos() {
  uint64_t now = mach_absolute_time();
  static struct Data {
    Data(uint64_t bias_) : bias(bias_) {
      kern_return_t mtiStatus = mach_timebase_info(&tb);
      assert(mtiStatus == KERN_SUCCESS);
    }
    uint64_t scale(uint64_t i) {
      return scaleHighPrecision(i - bias, tb.numer, tb.denom);
    }
    static uint64_t scaleHighPrecision(uint64_t i, uint32_t numer,
                                       uint32_t denom) {
      U64 high = (i >> 32) * numer;
      U64 low = (i & 0xffffffffull) * numer / denom;
      U64 highRem = ((high % denom) << 32) / denom;
      high /= denom;
      return (high << 32) + highRem + low;
    }
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;
    uint64_t bias;
  } data(now);
  return data.scale(now);
}
```

### A simple low-resolution answer

```cpp
// Returns monotonic time in nanos, measured from the first time the function
// is called in the process.  The clock may run up to 0.1% faster or slower
// than the "exact" tick count.
uint64_t monotonicTimeNanos() {
  uint64_t now = mach_absolute_time();
  static struct Data {
    Data(uint64_t bias_) : bias(bias_) {
      kern_return_t mtiStatus = mach_timebase_info(&tb);
      assert(mtiStatus == KERN_SUCCESS);
      if (tb.denom > 1024) {
        double frac = (double)tb.numer/tb.denom;
        tb.denom = 1024;
        tb.numer = tb.denom * frac + 0.5;
        assert(tb.numer > 0);
      }
    }
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;
    uint64_t bias;
  } data(now);
  return (now - data.bias) * data.tb.numer / data.tb.denom;
}
```

### A fiddly solution using low-precision arithmetic but using continued fractions to avoid loss of accuracy

```cpp
// This function returns the rational number inside the given interval with
// the smallest denominator (and smallest numerator breaks ties; correctness
// proof neglects floating-point errors).
static mach_timebase_info_data_t bestFrac(double a, double b) {
  if (floor(a) < floor(b))
  { mach_timebase_info_data_t rv = {(int)ceil(a), 1}; return rv; }
  double m = floor(a);
  mach_timebase_info_data_t next = bestFrac(1/(b-m), 1/(a-m));
  mach_timebase_info_data_t rv = {(int)m*next.numer + next.denum, next.numer};
  return rv;
}

// Returns monotonic time in nanos, measured from the first time the function
// is called in the process.  The clock may run up to 0.1% faster or slower
// than the "exact" tick count. However, although the bound on the error is
// the same as for the pragmatic answer, the error is actually minimized over
// the given accuracy bound.
uint64_t monotonicTimeNanos() {
  uint64_t now = mach_absolute_time();
  static struct Data {
    Data(uint64_t bias_) : bias(bias_) {
      kern_return_t mtiStatus = mach_timebase_info(&tb);
      assert(mtiStatus == KERN_SUCCESS);
      double frac = (double)tb.numer/tb.denom;
      uint64_t spanTarget = 315360000000000000llu; // 10 years
      if (getExpressibleSpan(tb.numer, tb.denom) >= spanTarget)
        return;
      for (double errorTarget = 1/1024.0; errorTarget > 0.000001;) {
        mach_timebase_info_data_t newFrac =
            bestFrac((1-errorTarget)*frac, (1+errorTarget)*frac);
        if (getExpressibleSpan(newFrac.numer, newFrac.denom) < spanTarget)
          break;
        tb = newFrac;
        errorTarget = fabs((double)tb.numer/tb.denom - frac) / frac / 8;
      }
      assert(getExpressibleSpan(tb.numer, tb.denom) >= spanTarget);
    }
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;
    uint64_t bias;
  } data(now);
  return (now - data.bias) * data.tb.numer / data.tb.denom;
}
```

#### The derivation

We aim to reduce the fraction returned by `mach_timebase_info` to one that is essentially the same, but with a small denominator. The size of the timespan that we can handle is limited only by the size of the denominator, not the numerator of the fraction we shall multiply by:

```cpp
uint64_t getExpressibleSpan(uint32_t numer, uint32_t denom) {
  // This is just less than the smallest thing we can multiply numer by without
  // overflowing. ceilLog2(numer) = 64 - number of leading zeros of numer
  uint64_t maxDiffWithoutOverflow = ((uint64_t)1 << (64 - ceilLog2(numer))) - 1;
  return maxDiffWithoutOverflow * numer / denom;
}
```

If `denom=33333335` as returned by `mach_timebase_info`, we can handle differences of up to 18 seconds only before the multiplication by numer overflows.  As `getExpressibleSpan` shows, by calculating a rough lower bound for this, the size of `numer` doesn't matter: halving `numer` doubles `maxDiffWithoutOverflow`. The only goal therefore is to produce a fraction close to numer/denom that has a smaller denominator. The simplest method to do this is using continued fractions.

The continued fractions method is rather handy. `bestFrac` clearly works correctly if the provided interval contains an integer: it returns the least integer in the interval over 1. Otherwise, it calls itself recursively with a strictly larger interval and returns `m+1/next`. The final result is a continued fraction that can be shown by induction to have the correct property: it's optimal, the fraction inside the given interval with the least denominator.

Finally, we reduce the fraction Darwin passes us to a smaller one to use when rescaling the `mach_absolute_time` to nanoseconds. We may introduce an error here because we can't reduce the fraction in general without losing accuracy. We set ourselves the target of 0.1% error, and check that we've reduced the fraction enough for common timespans (up to ten years) to be handled correctly.

Arguably the method is over-complicated for what it does, but it handles correctly anything the API can throw at it, and the resulting code is still short and extremely fast (`bestFrac` typically recurses only three or four iterations deep before returning a denominator less than 1000 for random intervals `[a,a*1.002]`).

Comment: That looks promising, unfortunately I can't seem to be able to make my compiler work with those (using a simple `clang foo.c`) (probably the `static struct Data {Data(uint64_t bias_) : bias(bias_) {` part which I've never seen) could you give me any clue?

Comment: It's C++ (ObjC++), not C.
Having said that, I should actually update this answer because I use a different technique now - just do the arithmetic at high-precision :)

Comment: Thanks :) I've came up with a different solution too (but have no PowerPC to test it actually works :p)

Comment: I've updated with my more-accurate solution now. We dropped support for PPC at my company a year ago, so it's all moot now that we're pretty-much guaranteed never to see anything other than `1/1` returned from `mach_timebase_info()`.

Comment: In the one with title "Perform the arithmetic at 128-bit precision to avoid the overflow!" `now` is passed to the ctor of `Data` which set `bias` to the value of `now`, then `now` is passed to `scale` and there `bias` is subtracted from `i`. Doesn't that mean that `now` is subtracted from `now`? ... I can't see how this isn't always zero?

Comment: You've missed that it's `static struct Data ...` so it's only zero the first time the function is called. After that the bias is remembered from previous runs.

Answer (score 5):

You're worrying about overflow when multiplying/dividing with values from the `mach_timebase_info` struct, which is used for conversion to nanoseconds. So, while it may not fit your exact needs, there are easier ways to get a count in nanoseconds or seconds.

All solutions below are using `mach_absolute_time` internally (and NOT the wall clock).

---

#### Use `double` instead of `uint64_t`

<sup>(supported in Objective-C and Swift)</sup>

```
double tbInSeconds = 0;
mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;
kern_return_t kError = mach_timebase_info(&tb);
if (kError == 0) {
    tbInSeconds = 1e-9 * (double)tb.numer / (double)tb.denom;
}
```

(remove the `1e-9` if you want nanoseconds)

Usage:

```
uint64_t start = mach_absolute_time();
// do something
uint64_t stop = mach_absolute_time();
double durationInSeconds = tbInSeconds * (stop - start);
```

---

#### Use ProcessInfo.processInfo.[systemUptime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime)

<sup>(supported in Objective-C and Swift)</sup>

It does the job in `double` seconds directly:

```
CFTimeInterval start = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime;
// do something
CFTimeInterval stop = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime;
NSTimeInterval durationInSeconds = stop - start;
```

For reference, [source code of systemUptime](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/NumberDate.subproj/CFDate.c)
just does something similar as previous solution:

```
struct mach_timebase_info info;
mach_timebase_info(&info);
__CFTSRRate = (1.0E9 / (double)info.numer) * (double)info.denom;
__CF1_TSRRate = 1.0 / __CFTSRRate;
uint64_t tsr = mach_absolute_time();
return (CFTimeInterval)((double)tsr * __CF1_TSRRate);
```

---

#### Use QuartzCore.[CACurrentMediaTime()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime)

<sup>(supported in Objective-C and Swift)</sup>

Same as `systemUptime`, but without being open source.

---

#### Use Dispatch.[DispatchTime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime).now()

<sup>(supported in Swift only)</sup>

Another wrapper around `mach_absolute_time()`. Base precision is nanoseconds, backed with `UInt64`.

```
DispatchTime start = DispatchTime.now()
// do something
DispatchTime stop = DispatchTime.now()
TimeInterval durationInSeconds = Double(end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000_000
```

For reference, [source code of `DispatchTime.now()`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/swift/Time.swift) says it basically simply returns a struct `DispatchTime(rawValue: mach_absolute_time())`. And the calculation for `uptimeNanoseconds` is:

```
(result, overflow) = result.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: UInt64(DispatchTime.timebaseInfo.numer))
result = overflow ? UInt64.max : result / UInt64(DispatchTime.timebaseInfo.denom)
```

So it just discards results if the multiplication can't be stored in an UInt64.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Most practical approach is to cache a `double` conversion coefficient for conversion to seconds. If you need max accuracy, stay in ticks domain and convert only for display/interop purposes.

Answer (score -1):

If `mach_absolute_time()` sets the uint64 back to 0 then reset the time calculations if less than the last check.

That's the problem, they don't document what happens when the uint64 reaches all ones (binary).

read it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1462446-mach_absolute_time

Comment: It will take more than 580 years for it to wrap around on Intel and more than 24000 years on Apple Silicon.

Comment: It will also get you ranked in the broad classification of fails eventually if not fixed and discussed as such with those not knowing of your stack overflow response.