# Measure elapsed time in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation, mach

I need to measure elapsed time, in order to know when a certain period of time has been exceeded.

I used to use `Ticks()` and `Microseconds()` for this, but both functions are now deprecated.

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` is not the correct way to use because it may run backwards, as explained in the docs:

> Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically
>   increasing results. The system time may decrease due to
>   synchronization with external time references or due to an explicit
>   user change of the clock.

What else is there that's not deprecated and fairly future-proof?

Comment: `mach_absolute_time`? Fascinating discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378063/how-can-i-use-mach-absolute-time-without-overflowing (Off-topic: Hi, Thomas!)

Comment: (Hi MattN!) Yes, thanks for the pointer about mach_absolute_time - I had found Q&A 1398 in the mean time but was not aware of the overflows. I'd expect there are other ways as well, though, maybe using timers (though I don't know if they're acting correctly if the clock changes back).

Comment: One of the other deprecated timing functions, `UpTime`, is declared in DriverServices.h.  Comments in that header say "Use CFAbsoluteTime or mach time routines instead".

Answer (score 2):

One way, as explained in [Q&A 1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html), is to use `mach_absolute_time` as follows:

```
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebaseInfo;
    mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo); // Determines the time scale

    uint64_t t1 = mach_absolute_time();
    ...
    uint64_t t2 = mach_absolute_time();
    uint64_t elapsedNano = (t2-t1) * sTimebaseInfo.numer / sTimebaseInfo.denom;
```

This may not be fool-proof either, though. The values could overflow in some cases, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378063/).

Comment: I've had good results with `mach_absolute_time`. A while back I made a little Cocoa class wrapper around it, as described [here](http://zpasternack.org/high-resolution-timing-in-cocoa-revisited/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSTimeInterval`:

> Used to specify a time interval, in seconds.

**Example:**

```
- (void)loop {

    NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];

    sleep(90); // sleep for 90 seconds

    [self elapsedTime:startTime];
}

- (void)elapsedTime:(NSDate *)startTime {

NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = fabs([startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]);

int intSeconds = (int) elapsedTime;
int intMinutes = intSeconds / 60;
intSeconds = intSeconds % 60;

NSLog(@"Elapsed Time: %d minute(s) %d seconds", intMinutes, intSeconds);

}
```

**Result:**

```
Elapsed Time: 1 minute(s) 29 seconds
```

It's unclear what type of precision you are looking for, although NSTimeInterval can accomodate fractions of a second (eg. tenths, hundredths, thousandths, etc.)

Comment: NSDate is, like CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent, able to run backwards, though, isn't it? I mean, a user could simply change his clock manually, and you already have it going back. Or isn't `timeIntervalSinceNow` prone to this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately almost any date/time method is prone to that. If you're worried about the possibility of it happening you could do a check within a specified interval of the elapsed time to determine if the current time is less than the start time — and if it is then invalidate it.